# Deletion button appearing below section index in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have my UITableView set up (in the standard way) to allow deletion on swipes.  Whenever I have a sectionindex showing, however, the "Delete" button appears /below/ the section index:

[image: Delete button below index]

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

I've tried setting the selected cell to be less wide in willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath, but this removes the seperator line below the cell too (i.e. the line is part of the cell, so doesn't draw in the area outside the cell's new bounds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we used is to remove the index when the table is in editing mode (the other option is, obviously, don't use both table features in the same table).

Comment: There's no way to do that from within willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath though, right?  Or have I overlooked something?

Editing mode (with a button to enter it etc.) is not enabled for my table; management of this data is primarily done from elsewhere, I just wanted to add swiping as an affordance.

Comment: You could try expanding the table right, off the screen, thought you might have to adjust your row widths. I think what I ended up doing was locating the index tab subview and animating it out of the way.

Comment: That (animating the index tab subview out) is what I've ended up doing, in as safe a manner as I can muster.  Makes me feel unclean though... :-(

Comment: you get used to that feeling :-)